# Easiest way to get the function's name using the function pointer

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, hook

I am writing a utility to get the memory used by the process while getting into the function and while getting out of the function for each function. I plan to do it in the _penter and _pexit functions. Is there a simple way to get the name of the function in _penter and _pexit? I have the pdb file of my executable. Can somebody help me to get it using `SymGetSymFromAddr64` and `StackWalk64`?

Comment: You want the name of the function which invoked `_penter`? Your question is not clear, additionally, are the functions imported/linked? Because you can look at the PEB module list, and then look at the modules exports and compare addresses. If the function is not exported, getting the function at runtime involves using debugging libraries you mentioned. Please clarify

Comment: @JakeHeidt Yes, I am trying to get the function that invoked the _penter and _pexit

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for a solution and I couldn't find it but managed to solve it myself here is what I used

`Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Command Line`

Add compiler option to `Additional Options` box

Like so [image: example settings]

> Add flag /Gh  for _penter hook
>
> Add flag /GH  for _pexit hook

Code I use for tracing / logging

```
#include <intrin.h>

extern "C"  void __declspec(naked) __cdecl _penter(void) {
    __asm {
        push ebp;               // standard prolog
        mov ebp, esp;
        sub esp, __LOCAL_SIZE
        pushad;                 // save registers
    }
    // _ReturnAddress always returns the address directly after the call, but that is not the start of the function!
    PBYTE addr;
    addr = (PBYTE)_ReturnAddress() - 5;

    SYMBOL_INFO* mysymbol;
    HANDLE       process;
    process = GetCurrentProcess();
    SymInitialize(process, NULL, TRUE);
    mysymbol = (SYMBOL_INFO*)calloc(sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + 256 * sizeof(char), 1);
    mysymbol->MaxNameLen = 255;
    mysymbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);
    SymFromAddr(process, (DWORD64)((void*)addr), 0, mysymbol);
    myprintf("Entered Function: %s [0x%X]\n", mysymbol->Name, addr);

    _asm {
        popad;              // restore regs
        mov esp, ebp;       // standard epilog
        pop ebp;
        ret;
    }
}
```

```
extern "C"  void __declspec(naked) __cdecl _pexit(void) {
    __asm {
        push ebp;               // standard prolog
        mov ebp, esp;
        sub esp, __LOCAL_SIZE
        pushad;                 // save registers
    }
    // _ReturnAddress always returns the address directly after the call, but that is not the start of the function!
    PBYTE addr;
    addr = (PBYTE)_ReturnAddress() - 5;

    SYMBOL_INFO* mysymbol;
    HANDLE       process;
    process = GetCurrentProcess();
    SymInitialize(process, NULL, TRUE);
    mysymbol = (SYMBOL_INFO*)calloc(sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + 256 * sizeof(char), 1);
    mysymbol->MaxNameLen = 255;
    mysymbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);
    SymFromAddr(process, (DWORD64)((void*)addr), 0, mysymbol);
    myprintf("Exit Function: %s [0x%X]\n", mysymbol->Name, addr);

    _asm {
        popad;              // restore regs
        mov esp, ebp;       // standard epilog
        pop ebp;
        ret;
    }
}
```